# Attempt to invoke interface method on a null object reference finishComposingText()

Tags: java, android, testing, robotium

I am running robotium on a nexus 6 and getting the following error

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method      'boolean android.view.inputmethod.InputConnection.finishComposingText()' on      a null object reference
 at android.view.inputmethod.InputConnectionWrapper.finishComposingText(InputConnectionWrapper.java:78)
 at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.reportFinishInputConnection(InputMethodManager.java:859)
 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:3253)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

The line in question is:

```
     solo.enterText((android.widget.EditText) solo.getView("amount"), "11.11");
```

I have verified that the field exists, not sure what else could be causing the problem.  Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Well, I'd *start* by extracting the `EditText` part as a local variable, so you can be *sure* that you've managed to get it (so it's not a `null` value) before you pass it to the method...

Comment: solo.getView is returning an instance of the EditText

Comment: any solutions ? i m running into the same issue...

Comment: Same problem for me, any solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you getting wrong EditText since you confirmed that returned instance is EditText.

```
android.widget.EditText editText= (android.widget.EditText)solo.getView("amount");
// validate here that you got right text by any method, for example getText()
solo.enterText(editText, "11.11");
```

and if this one doesn't work you can use direct access without solo:

```
editText.setText("11.11");
```

Comment: im going to accept this.  I had issue years ago and can't remember what I did to fix it.  Thanks for answering

Answer (score 8):

This happened to me because of Advanced Profiling option is enabled.
To disable the advanced profiling, follow these steps:

1.Select Run > Edit Configurations.
2.Select your app module in the left pane.
3.Click the Profiling tab, and then uncheck Enable advanced profiling.

Comment: Not every hero wear capes